# Import exchange management session into powershell

Tags: powershell

I get user credential from  user using gui

```
$userid =$email.text
$password = $Password.text
$Session = New-PSSession -Authentication default -credential($userid,$passowrd) -ConnectionUri https://$ip/powershell -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck -SkipCACheck)
        Import-PSSession $Session
```

when i pass user name and password to session variable it's throw an error
how can i pass this two value so that  can import exchange management session to powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$userid = $email.text
$password = $Password.text | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userid, $password

$Session = New-PSSession -Authentication default -Credential $credential -ConnectionUri https://$ip/powershell -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCNCheck -SkipCACheck)
Import-PSSession $Session
```